# Why is this code throwing an exception when using dynamic memory allocation?

Tags: c++, pointers, exception, memory, dynamic

The below program creates a new array of structs of `[n+5]` elements, every time the quantity reaches `5`, `10`, `15`, ... and copies the old elements to a new array.

This is the error thrown:

> Exception thrown at 0x7AE740DF (vcruntime140d.dll) in ConsoleApplication4.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x6CBFEBB8.

The error is thrown on line 69, where it says `items += 1;`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

struct item{
    string name;
    int eff;
};

item* ptr = nullptr;
item* temp = nullptr;
int itemsA = 0;
int arrSize = 5;
int lastElement = 0;


void func(int&, item *& ,int&, int& , item*&);

int main()
{
    ptr = new item[arrSize];

    func(arrSize, ptr,itemsA,lastElement, temp);


}
void func(int& arrSize, item *& ptr, int &items, int&lastElement, item *& temp)
{
    bool event = false;
    int a = 1;
    while (a == 1)
    {
        cout << "Your array size is: " << arrSize << endl;
        if (items > arrSize)
        {
            temp = new item[arrSize];

            for (int x = 0; x < arrSize; x++)
            {
                temp[x].eff = ptr[x].eff;
                temp[x].name = ptr[x].name;
            }
            arrSize += 5;
            delete[] ptr;
            ptr = nullptr;
            ptr = new item[arrSize];

            for (int x = 0; x < arrSize; x++)
            {
                ptr[x].name = temp[x].name;
                ptr[x].eff = temp[x].eff;
            }
            delete[] temp;
            temp = nullptr;

        }
        int any;
        string any2;
        cout << "ENter name for position number: " << lastElement + 1 << "\n";
        cin >> any2;
        cout << "ENter int for hp effect for position number: " << lastElement + 1 << "\n";
        cin >> any;
        ptr[lastElement].eff = any;
        ptr[lastElement].name = any2;
        items +=1;                                //////////the error is thrown here
        cout << "You now have " << items << " items.\n";


        cout << "Items in your bag: \n";
        for (int x = 0; x < items; x++)
        {
            cout << ptr[x].name << " which gives you extra " << ptr[x].eff << " health when used.\n";
        }
        lastElement += 1;

    }
}
```

Comment: The second `for` loop in `func()` accesses elements of `temp` past the end.  You subsequent code does not check that `lastElement` is a valid index for `ptr`, but uses it as an index.    Accessing an invalid index of an array (dynamically allocated or not) does not magically resize that array - it simply causes undefined behaviour.

Comment: Unrelated: To be able to analyse programming problems, try to make every little part of the program clear. A function should have _one_ function/purpose. If the descriptive name of a function would need to be longer than the code performing the function, split the function up in parts. If you come up with a name for a function like `a_function_that_first_does_this_and_then_this_but_only_if_that` it's a sure sign that you should split it. Your `main` (proxied via a call to a `void func(int&, item *& ,int&, int& , item*&);`) looks like it has some of that.

Comment: @Peter, thank you for your tip regarding the for loop. As soon as I fixed this problem the code worked as expected. As for the  int lastElement being used as an index, this was my idea of how to access the last empty element in the array. Of course this might be wrong as I am new to coding, but from your answer I do not quite understand why is it a problem. Anyways following your first tip helped me a lot, so I'd like to thank you once again.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thank you for the tip! My code looks way better now

Comment: @MichaelMichael - I'm not quite sure what you mean.    If an array has (say) two elements, then accessing the third element gives undefined behaviour.    It isn't a magical way to recognise the last element of the array.

Answer (score 1):

You're accessing the array out of bounds.  When `items == arrSize`, you try to write to `ptr[lastElement]`, which, since `lastElement` and `items` will have the same value, will write to `ptr[arrSize]` which is past the end of the allocated space.

There are also numerous problems in your array expansion code, and you're passing parameters that you don't need to.

Comment: Thanks! It helped me to fix the code! As for your second remark, what parameters are not required?

Comment: @MichaelMichael You're passing variables to `func` that should be locals instead (like `temp`).